# Return the concatenated string of properties via single Cypher call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the next graph:

*Theme* *Contains* multiple *Stories*. *Theme* and *Story* are graph nodes, connected via *Contains* relation.

Each node has property *name*.

I would like to write a Cypher query so it returns the concatenated string from names.

E.g. Theme.name = "theme name", Story1.name = "s1 name", Story2.name = "s2 name". Query result expected: "theme name s1 name s2 name".

How that can be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a couple of choices, using either REDUCE or apoc.text.join (from the apoc procedures in 3.x)

something like this  -

```
MATCH (t:Theme)-[:Contains]->(s:Story)
RETURN REDUCE(result=t.name, s in collect(s.name) | result+" "+s)
```

Or using APOC

```
MATCH (t:Theme)-[:Contains]->(s:Story)
RETURN apoc.text.join(t.name+collect(s.name)," ")
```